# A Master Sheet / Template for Google Sheets similar to a Slide Master for Slides/Powerpoint

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

How do I create a Master Sheet with formulas that, whenever those formulas are updated, it updates those formulas in sheets made by copying it? So whenever changes are made to the Master Sheet, linked sheets are updated with the same changes in terms of formulas. And if possible structure as well, so if a column is added, that also gets added to all linked sheets.

Very much like how a slide master works. You know, how if you update a header/footer or add a text box/image in a slide master it updates that in every slave slide of that template.

**A scenario**: A school enters data through a google form. This is then brought into separate sheets for every class. Say I have 15 classes total. These are then updated by the class teachers with things like say attendance. Now if I change one small thing in one of those class sheets, I have to edit all 15 sheets.

Link to sample google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18aPWgfoAcc4NUyvK3hJcFfP6rW2zgFF9NrtgT8NRFjs/edit?usp=sharing

Sometimes Macros work but not always and a new one must be made each time, and then run for each sheet. This is not efficient if you have 63 sheets to update like me.

It feels like one of those things that should already be there! Must be good reasons not to be.

Is there a way to do this either through formulas or through code? I haven't done scripts so would appreciate any help. If possible a method that is data agnostic.

PS: If this can't be done, is there a way to define a macro that works for multiple sheets?

Comment: Do these help? https://blog.google/products/g-suite/g-suite-pro-tips-how-sync-one-spreadsheet-another-google-sheets/
 and 
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/google-sheets-ways-to-combine-multiple-sheets/
 and 
https://coefficient.io/linking-data-between-multiple-google-sheets
 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729989/push-updates-to-multiple-google-sheets-from-master-sheet
 and 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsqjUxBcgAs

Comment: Thanks Gantendo for putting these resources together. I appreciate the effort and I went through all of them. But they are not quite doing what I need. I'm not looking to combine data from several sheets. Instead more like define a structure template that multiple sheets use, that I can update by updating the template instead of individually updating each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to do this either through formulas or through code.*

**By formula**
*Maybe*. It would depend on the specific formula and how it is structured.

If you want to add a brand new formula, then *No*.

**By code**
*Yes... probably*.
Why "probably"? While there are script methods to make and update variables (such as [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setvaluevalue)) and/or formula (such as [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setformulaformula), you haven't given any information about your sheets, data, the formula that you use, etc.

So while there is a *very high probability* that the changes can be made with a script, a more detailed response would need more information that the hypothetical in this question.

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz for taking the time to reply. 
The reason that I did not provide a sample sheet, is that I would have preferred a method that was data agnostic. It should not matter what the sheet contained. 

However I spent some time making a redacted version of the school sheet for your perusal. I hope that this helps. 

Link to google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18aPWgfoAcc4NUyvK3hJcFfP6rW2zgFF9NrtgT8NRFjs/edit?usp=sharing

This is only one scenario though. I have another for program with 63 people updating data each with their own sheet.

Comment: A script option *is* possible. Whether it would be sensible, practical or advisable is another thing altogether.

Comment: Could I possibly use a macro to add some level of efficiency beyond manually updating each change in each sheet?

Comment: Or are there other methods that could be of use that I am not aware of ?

Comment: My understanding is that a `macro` is a `script` by another name - there's just a non-technical way of generating the code. But in your case, since you "might" need changes to have a more specific purpose, and in specific places on "many" sheets, I think a script would be far more efficient. Having said that, we're discussing a hypothetical situation so you can try and macro and see what happens.

Comment: "Are there other methods that could be of use that I am not aware of ?" Not that I know of... except I would venture to say that you have built a VERY complicated spreadsheet and that possibly this is just the tip of the iceberg (no daily home room or class attendance records, no subject performance records, etc,) and this single spreadsheet is to be used by 60+ teachers?? There is no quick fix for your "Template" vision, but I would advocate multiple Teacher-centric spreadsheets that you can access to consolidate data. But that is purely my opinion (which is off topic).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to consider alternatives. It is very much appreciated. I guess no help for the weary!   The spreadsheet as it is, is not overly complicated from a user standpoint. This is primarily to help track attendance records. 
I understand your approach of having the data in "teacher centric" sheets and then aggregating it. And that is pretty much what is happening in terms of data flow, teacher enters in their sheet and then it is shows up in the dashboard. However those teacher centric sheets still have to be edited manually anytime a formula is updated.

Comment: To go a little deeper, the data first comes into the sheet through a form. The form collects the student information as they gain admission, It then segregates that data based on grades into separate sheets. Each of the these grade sheets have the same format.  The teachers are able to update attendance details on a monthly basis, which gets aggregated in the dashboard. We call grades, class here. 

But I guess there is nothing but elbow grease for now!  Although it just feels like being able to build structural template sheets, is something that would be of great use in many scenarios.